# iOS - how to receive bug reports via email from a device without mail client set up?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, email, bug-reporting

I will have an app deployed to business iPads that would be given to customers and typically would not have a mail client set up. I would like to collect debug information from the app and have the user be able to send it, so I can receive it via email.

**How can I receive email with bug reports from an app that does not have a native mail client set up?** That is I cannot present a mail composer, because it is not configured and cannot send mail.

One way I'm thinking of is to create my own web service that will process a data packet and email it, but what other options do I have?

Comment: We needed to do this and set up a simple Python cgi app on a server to receive debug data from our app over TCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend two different services.

[Crashlytics](https://www.crashlytics.com/) is a service that I started using recently. It tracks usage in the app automatically, and allows you to view it online (monthly users, device, OS, etc.). However, the most useful feature IMO is that it sends you an email if and when your app crashes, along with the crash report and the exact line it crashed on.

[`SendGrid`](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-objc) is another option if you're looking to send yourself customized debug data. Basically, you can send emails in the background of your app without the user knowing. **If you're looking to send automated emails in the background, this is the way to go.**

I have used both in my own applications, and both have been very helpful in their respective ways.

Comment: I'm also using Crashlytics for a lot of Apps. Working very good, it's also done by Twitter.